# How do I return to an existing tab after closing a new tab?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I redirect my user back to an existing tab?

When a user signs in to my app, I open a new tab (using `window.open(url, '_blank')`) to contain the signin sequence. After the user completes the signin, I want that tab to close and return to tab that was active before the new tab was opened.

Here is a screenshot of the application when the user is unknown:

[image: unknown startup]

When the user clicks the "Signin" button at top right, here is a screenshot showing the second tab (containing the password challenge from Auth0):

[image: password challenge]

At the successful conclusion of the signin, here is the placeholder behavior. The `Switch` complains because I don't know what to do in response to the "continuation" URL:

[image]

Here is what the application looks like after a successful signin. I get this by manually refreshing the browser after closing the second tab. Note the Avatar at the top right.

[image]

How do I programmatically cause the final screen shot? I want to close the second tab, return to the first tab, and force a render.

I'm lost in the weeds of "window.open" and the behaviors of `react-router-dom`. My authentication provider is Auth0, and so the application already has a `Auth0ProviderWithHistory` context as well as a `Router` around that. That `Auth0ProviderWithHistory` already has code that's doing something with `history`:

```
const history = useHistory();

const onRedirectCallback = (appState) {
  history.push(appState?.returnTo || window.location.pathname);
}
```

I'm new enough to `react-router-dom` that I don't really grok what the `useHistory` and `useParams` hooks do. At the top of my app, I have a dispatcher that uses `Switch` and `Route` to determine the contents that appear in whatever tab is open. The flow through the several signin stages that use the dispatcher seems to work fine. Here is the `AppDispatcher` that I'm currently using:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Box,
} from '@mui/material';

import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import AppContainer from './AppContainer';
import LoginPersonaContainer from './login_persona/LoginPersonaContainer';
import SigninPersonaContainer from './login_persona/SigninPersonaContainer';
import SuccessContainer from './login_persona/SuccessContainer';
import ClosedContainer from './login_persona/ClosedContainer';

const NoMatch = ({ location }) => (
  <Box>
    <strong>Error!</strong> No route found matching:
    {location.pathname}
  </Box>
);

const AppDispatcher = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route
        path="/"
        exact = {true}
        component={AppContainer}
      />
      <Route
        path='/loginPersona/login'
        component = {LoginPersonaContainer}
      />
      <Route
        path='/loginPersona/signin'
        component = {SigninPersonaContainer}
      />
      <Route
        path='/loginPersona/success'
        component = {SuccessContainer}
      />
      <Route
        path='/loginPersona/closed'
        component = {ClosedContainer}
      />
      <Route
        component={NoMatch}
      />
    </Switch>
  );
}

export default AppDispatcher;
```

I don't see a way to cause the second tab on the browser to close while returning control to the initial tab -- and forcing a render on that tab so that it will reflect the results of the signin.

When the code in the second window just closes the window (`window.close`), the tab closes but the original window doesn't render. I've tried a variety of alternatives, and they either open a third tab or render the original window's content in the new tab. Neither of those is acceptable.

What `react-browser-dom` or `window` incantation causes the "signin" tab to close, return control to the original tab, and force a render/refresh of the original window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the second tab loads, You can use

```
window.opener.document.location.href = "http://localhost:3000"
window.close()
```

This will go back to the parent tab, and cause it to re-render. Then the second tab will also be closed.

You have to make sure that this code only runs when you visit the route on the second tab

You can find more information about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener

---

[I (Tom Stambaugh)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1723615/tom-stambaugh) updated the `ClosedContainer` to reflect the above answer and it works as requested. Here is my update close handler:

```
  const handleClosed = () => {
    console.log(`ClosedContainer.handleClose()`);
    window.opener.document.location.href = "https://localhost:3003";
    window.close();
  }
```

Comment: I appreciate your immediate and helpful response! I'll investigate this further. If I do the first line of your answer just before calling `window.open`, then perhaps the `window.close` will just do the right thing? I'll dig into this -- thanks!

Comment: No worries!
When you write 
```window.opener.document.location.href = "http://localhost:3000"```
You're telling your second tab, to tell the first tab to go to that url. For this to work, the tab the code is being run must have been opened from another tab using
```window.open```. 

What you can do is to make the redirect_uri of the authentication go to a different route, like ```http://localhost:3000/auth_redirect``` which will then close the second tab, and go back to the first one with the appropriate url